# Cannot build Native Module on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I'm following the guide here to create a new React Native Module.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup

I can build and run the example app on iOS, but if I try and build the Xcode project for the library (top level static library project), I keep getting this error.

```
path-to-project/iOS/MyProjectReactNative-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
```

This error is happening in the Swift bridging header. If I comment those lines out it will build, but then I get an error about unresolved types for RCTPromiseResolveBlock and RCTPromiseRejectBlock.

I see these headers files are here. I've tried various ways to add this folder to my header search paths, but that hasn't worked.

```
path-to-project/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/
```

I want to add my own native functions to this project for the example app.